# firebase auth Invalide codepin sended known that i set the right code

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase phone number authentification  and i have problem in the verification when i send the code and i set it it tell me that its invalide code known that the phone that i test with is not the same contain the simcard
there is 2 button when for the sending and one for the verifying 
sending button call the onphonenumbersubmited and the verifying call the oncodepin submited this functions use the same signin function in case of succes

```
 public void OnPhoneNumberSubmitted(String phoneNumber) {
    //getting firebase phone auth provider instance
    final PhoneAuthProvider phoneAuthProvider = PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance();
    //verifying phone number, using my personne l phone number, setting 1 minute as a time out for the second attempt
    phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber, // the phone number of the user
            60,  // the time out
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, // the time out unit
            this,   // maneging the activity life cycle change
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                    //some devices, can detect automatically the sent pinCode
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                    //something went wrong while submitting the pinCode
                    Toast.makeText(validation_emailphonenumber.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // Invalid request
                        Toast.makeText(validation_emailphonenumber.this,"Invalid request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                        // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                        Toast.makeText(validation_emailphonenumber.this," The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

                @SuppressLint("CommitTransaction")
                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    //the user received the pinCode
                    super.onCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
                    //saving the verification Id to use later
                    mPhoneVerificationId = verificationId;
                    // Toast the code has been sent
                    Toast.makeText(validation_emailphonenumber.this,"The verification code has been sent "
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //stating the pinCodee Fragment
                    Phone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    send_pinCode_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout,
                            pinCodeFragment,
                            pinCodeFragment.getTag()).commit();

                   /* getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frameLayout,pinCodeFragment)
                            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit(); */
                }
            }
    );

}


private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(final PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"signIn Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(validation_emailphonenumber.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid verification number"+credential.getProvider(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"signInWithCredential:failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });
}






//pinCodee Fragment  Functions
public void Checkcode (View view) {

    codeinput = findViewById(R.id.pinCode_editText);
    String codepin = codeinput.getText().toString();
    onPinCodeSubmitted(codepin);

}

public void onPinCodeSubmitted(String codePin) {
    if(validateCredentials(codePin)){
        PhoneAuthCredential credential= PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codePin,mPhoneVerificationId);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }
```